# Definir permissões para app em tempo de execução

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, mobile

Existem alguns app's que quando a gente vai abrir pela primeira vez ele pede permissão ao usuário para ativar determinados recursos do aparelho, como câmera, agenda de contatos, etc...

Como fazer com que a permissão seja pedido no momento em que o mesmo é aberto ao invés do momento que se faz a instalação?

Comment: Ao você fazer a utilização da `camera` por exemplo, assim que for executado a tal função, ele irá solicitar a permissão.

Comment: Isso não acontece. Apenas no momento da instalação e não no momento da execução. Estou testando em um motog5, isso teria alguma influencia em versão de android, configurações etc?

Comment: Sim, tem sim. Se você citar quais permissões que você está tentando acessar, fica mais facil te ajudar

Comment: As permissões que o aplicativo deve pedir ao usuário quando for aberto são: Identidade, Contatos, Localização, SMS, Telefone, Fotos/midias/arquivos, Câmera, Informações de conexão Wi-fi, ID do dispositivo/informações de chamada, IMEI do aparelho

Comment: O foco é o dispositivo pedir permissões no momento que for aberto pelo usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Para as versões do Android 6 ou superiores é obrigatório que as permissões perigosas sejam pedidas em tempo de execução, logo é importante saber disso.

Permissões como acesso a internet e configuração de Wi-Fi não são consideradas perigosas, mas acesso a câmera, dados etc são consideradas. O Android não permite que o app tenha acesso à funcionalidade com o tipo de permissão antiga, ou seja, pedir na instalação não funciona em Android igual ou superior à versão 6.

Comment: Esta solução é utilizando Cordova para aplicativos híbridos ou apenas para Android?

Comment: Não sei se exatamente se essa solução vai lhe ajudar, porque só programo em java no android, mas sei que com certeza vocẽ vai ter que pedir permissão em tempo de execução versões igual ou superior à 6

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o plugin [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) do Cordova para diagnóstico e solicitação de permissão.

[Aqui](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-android-runtime-example) você pode encontrar um exemplo de uso.